# Azure Logic app and custom DNS

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is is possible, and if so how, to have a custom dns point to my Azure logic app url?  For instance, I have 2 logic apps, one sends an email and one is an unsubscribe logic app.  There is a link in the email to point to my unsubscribe logic app. The URL is not user friendly.  Is there a way to create a DNS alias to point with a more fitting url like https://something.mysiteaddress.com insead of https://azurewebsiteurl.com?

Comment: We actually solved it short term by creating a azure function which pointed to the logic app instead.  We are going to be implementing api management later.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with [Azure Functions Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) but a better option might be API Management. You can configure custom domains for both.

The documentation for API Management includes an article on how to [Configure a custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain).

Answer (score -1):

You can initiate your logic app from your website. When someone hit your URL call logic app url from that URL.

Comment: The answer doesn't pertain to the question.